# Direction of induced EMF due to increasing or decreasing current?

Tags: electric-current, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

The direction of induced emf will be opposite to increasing current ;means that its direction will be opposite to applied voltage. And the direction of induced emf due to decreasing current will be same as that of applied voltage. Ok,now my question is does it mean that direction of induced emf due to increasing current is same as induced emf due to decreasing voltage?

Comment: Accelerating magnetic and electric fields produce electromagnetic radiation. Even a direct current which is supposedly a stationary electric field in the wire produces extremely low frequency radiation (ELF) just like a spinning or vibrating magnet would do. Typically they don't like to talk about such things. Either way the radiation follows typical rules magnetic field right hand rule circle around the electric field(lines from negative to positive end of wire and around the wire from negative to positive in ellipses that travel outwards)

Answer (score 0):

Applied voltage doesn't enter into it.

In an inductor when current is controlled the induced EMF opposes the change in current.

If you assume a steady state, then the quote is correct, but is does not describe the general situation.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what are you saying? I can't get your point

Answer (score 0):

In an inductor, the magnitude of the induced emf is proportional to the magnitude of the rate of change of the current (which can be + or -).

Answer (score 0):

My diagram shows how I think of what's going on. The emf opposes the rate of increase of current. This urges positive charge to the left (or negative charge to the right). The imbalance of charge gives a potential drop from left to right.

This explanation is maybe not along the expected lines, as we're probably used to thinking of potential differences as causing currents or changes in currents, and not the other way round. But what we consider *cause* and what we consider *effect* are a matter of taste when we are dealing with things that occur simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: If anyone can tell me of an application that will enable me to draw diagrams like this (but more nicely) I'd be very grateful.